# Docusign polling policy

Tags: docusignapi

I found the polling limitation and the documentation around it a bit vague as to what is considered polling so I was hoping that someone can help me understand if I will have a problem with my current flow.

My understanding is that polling is considered requesting envelope statuses but on a per document/envelope basis and you are not supposed to request that in less than 5min since you sent another request.

**So my question is this:**

My integration is creating a new envelope/new doc for each transaction and as soon as the doc is signed I make a request for the doc status.

Will I have a problem with this flow if the requests are not 5mins apart and considering its a new document/envelope each time?

Comment: The time between polling is strictly for status. So if you create an envelope and immediately get status, you should not request status for that envelope for another _n_ minutes (whatever n is in DocuSign's policy)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are creating a new envelope and as soon as the doc is signed you make a request for status.  How do you know a given recipient has just signed?  And if they did, why would you then request status right after you know it was signed?  Are you using `eventNotifications` or DocuSign Connect to know when the event happened?

Comment: The other thing is that the polling limit you've listed is incorrect, it's 15 minutes per envelope not 5.  The 5 minute example on the Certification page of the Dev Center is an example of something that's not acceptable.  When in doubt check the API docs, more specifically this page in particular:  https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#GettingStarted/API Call Limits.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7C_____2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocuSign has API rate limits in place for polling envelopes as well as an overall hourly limit per account:

A given account is allowed up to `1,000` API calls per hour.  Additionally, you may not exceed 1 status request per unique envelope per 15 mins. In other words, if you make a GET status request on an envelope, your integration will need to wait at least 15 minutes to request status on that same envelope again.

A couple of things you should consider:

1. Instead of polling the DocuSign service every so often, you can use the [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/connect) module to push status, documents, and other metadata out to you as soon as a given event occurs. (Note:  DocuSign Connect is a paid module)
2. You can also use the `eventNotification` property in your envelopes to have the DocuSign service push that data out to you (this uses the same engine as Connect but is free).

So you have a few options here- you can poll for status every 15 mins or more on the same envelope, or you can use one of the two methods for having DocuSign push that data out to you as soon as certain events occur.

Lastly, [THIS PAGE](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#GettingStarted/API%20Call%20Limits.htm%3FTocPath%3DGetting%2520Started%7C_____2) of the API documentation explains the rate limits in more detail.  You can also use that same link to learn more about the `eventNotification` feature, just search for that term in the search bar.